# error in readNetFromTensorflow in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, keras

I'm new in deep learning. In first step I create and train a model in python with keras and freezed by this code:

```
def export_model(MODEL_NAME, input_node_name, output_node_name):

    tf.train.write_graph(K.get_session().graph_def, 'out', \
        MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt')

    tf.train.Saver().save(K.get_session(), 'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp')

    freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out/' + MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt', None, \
        False, 'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp', output_node_name, \
        "save/restore_all", "save/Const:0", \
        'out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")

    input_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.Open('out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', "rb") as f:
        input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    output_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(
            input_graph_def, [input_node_name], [output_node_name],
            tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

    with tf.gfile.FastGFile('out/opt_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

it's output :

- checkpoint
- Model.chkp.data-00000-of-00001
- Model.chkp.index
- Model.chkp.meta
- Model_graph.pbtxt
- frozen_Model.pb
- opt_Model.pb

when I want to read the net in opencv c++ by readNetFromTensorflow :

```
String weights = "frozen_Model.pb";
String pbtxt = "Model_graph.pbtxt";
dnn::Net cvNet = cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(weights, pbtxt);
```

This will make error :

> OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) Error: Unspecified error (FAILED: ReadProtoFromBinaryFile(param_file, param). Failed to parse GraphDef file: frozen_Model.pb) in cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie, file D:\LIBS\OpenCV-4.00\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_io.cpp, line 44

and

> OpenCV(4.0.0-pre) Error: Assertion failed (const_layers.insert(std::make_pair(name, li)).second) in cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_v4::`anonymous-namespace'::addConstNodes, file D:\LIBS\OpenCV-4.00\modules\dnn\src\tensorflow\tf_importer.cpp, line 555

How to fix this error?

Comment: Try not to pass an optional `.pbtxt` file: `cv::dnn::readNetFromTensorflow(weights)`

Comment: @DmitryKurtaev -- does not work !

Comment: So paste a minimal working example. Attach a code which is used to define your network.

Comment: Hi. What is input and output node name in the function argument?

Answer (score 1):

Amin, may I ask you to try to save a graph in a testing mode:

```
K.backend.set_learning_phase(0)  # <--- This setting makes all the following layers work in test mode

model = Sequential(name = MODEL_NAME)
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation = 'relu',name = 'FirstLayerConv2D_No1',input_shape = (Width, Height, image_channel)))
...
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'softmax', name = 'endNode'))

# Create a graph definition (with no weights)
sess = K.backend.get_session()
sess.as_default()
tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), "", 'graph_def.pb', as_text=False)
```

Then freeze your checkpoint files with a newly created `graph_def.pb` by a [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) script (do not forget to use `--input_binary` flag).

Answer (score 0):

**Part of the code :**
**Create model, train and export_model**

```
train_batch = gen.flow_from_directory(path + 'Train', target_size = (Width, Height), shuffle = False, color_mode = color_mode,
       batch_size = batch_size_train, class_mode = 'categorical')
.
.
X_train, Y_train = next(train_batch)
.
.
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape).astype('float32')
.  
.
model = Sequential(name = MODEL_NAME)
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (5, 5), activation = 'relu',name = 'FirstLayerConv2D_No1',input_shape = (Width, Height, image_channel)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
.
.
.
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(200, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'softmax', name = 'endNode'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
   optimizer = SGD(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0.9), metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = batch_size_fit, epochs = epoch, shuffle = True,
         verbose = 1, validation_split = .1, validation_data = (X_test, Y_test))
export_model(MODEL_NAME, "FirstLayerConv2D_No1/Relu", "endNode/Softmax")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing the graph in `python` you need to do the following steps:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    # 1. Load saved model
    saved_model = tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], SAVED_MODEL_PATH)

    # 2. Convert variables to constants
    inference_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, saved_model.graph_def, OUTPUT_NODE_NAMES)

    # 3. Optimize for inference
    optimized_graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(inference_graph_def,
        INPUT_NODE_NAMES,
        OUTPUT_NODE_NAMES,
        tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)

    # 4. Save .pb file
    tf.train.write_graph(optimized_graph_def, MODEL_DIR, 'model_name.pb', as_text=False)

    # 5. Transform graph
    transforms = [
        'strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape=\"1,128,128,3\")',
        'remove_nodes(op=PlaceholderWithDefault)',
        'remove_device',
        'sort_by_execution_order'
    ]

    transformed_graph_def = TransformGraph(optimized_graph_def,
                                           INPUT_NODE_NAMES,
                                           OUTPUT_NODE_NAMES,
                                           transforms)

   # 6. Remove constant nodes and attributes
   for i in reversed(range(len(transformed_graph_def.node))):
       if transformed_graph_def.node[i].op == "Const":
           del transformed_graph_def.node[i]
       for attr in ['T', 'data_format', 'Tshape', 'N', 'Tidx', 'Tdim',
                    'use_cudnn_on_gpu', 'Index', 'Tperm', 'is_training', 'Tpaddings']:
           if attr in transformed_graph_def.node[i].attr:
               del transformed_graph_def.node[i].attr[attr]

   # 7. Save .pbtxt file
   tf.train.write_graph(transformed_graph_def, MODEL_DIR, 'model_name.pbtxt', as_text=True)
```

Plus, if you have special nodes as `Flatten`, you need to remove and rename some nodes manually.

More info [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/183507/opencv-dnn-import-error-for-keras-pretrained-vgg16-model/).