# Grayscale image classification with neural network on Android with OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, neural-network

I'm working on and android app that can digitize numbers from a paper. I use native OpenCV code to find the numbers on the image. After that I want to use OpenCV's dnn module to recognise the number. A nice tutorial on creating the neural net can be found here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFWKdLOxykE 
The *mnist_convnet_graph.pbtxt* begins with this:

```
node {
  name: "conv2d_1_input"
  op: "Placeholder"
  attr {
    key: "dtype"
    value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
  }
  attr {
    key: "shape"
    value {
      shape {
        dim {
          size: -1
        }
        dim {
          size: 28
        }
        dim {
          size: 28
        }
        dim {
          size: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So the input is a 28x28 grayscale image.
In the tutorial java code is used to use the neural net. However, I would like to use it in C++, because of the speed. I successfully load the model with *cv::dnn::Net Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(String model, String config);* and pass the object to the NDK side. I create the input for the neural net with the following:

```
// The part of the image, we are interested in.
Rect roi(static_cast<int>(w), static_cast<int>(h),
             static_cast<int>(w), static_cast<int>(h));
Mat cropped(image_gray, roi);
// Resize image to 28x28.
Mat resized;
cv::resize(cropped, resized, Size(28,28));
```

After that, the forwarding should work:

```
const double IN_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.003921; // 1.0/255.0
Mat blob = dnn::blobFromImage(resized, IN_SCALE_FACTOR, Size(28,28));
net.setInput(blob);
Mat detections = net.forward();
```

where *net* is the passed cv::dnn::Net object. But the *net.forward()* command fails and gives: 
OpenCV(3.4.5) Error: Assertion failed (inputs.size() == requiredOutputs) in virtual bool cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes(const std::vector >&, int, std::vector >&, std::vector >&) const, file /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp, line 681

I also tried:

- cropping the rgb image
- *Mat blob = dnn::blobFromImage(resized, 1.0f, Size(28,28));*
- Not using blobFromImage, but *net.setInput(resized);* instead

but none of these led to the solutions. Anyone has a solutions for this? Any suggestion or idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please provide an output from `std::cout << blob.size << std::endl`?

Comment: Sure. It is a 1x1x28x28 image. I don't know if it's appropriate for the input. Because in the mnist_convnet_graph.pbtxt file the order is not the same.

Comment: `1x1x28x28` is OK. It's just different data layout which OpenCV can manage. Could you please share an entire text `.pbtxt` file to see it? And please specify version of OpenCV you use. BTW, have you tried to import model using just a binary `.pb` file?

Comment: Sure. It's here: [link](https://pastebin.com/d4C2AeDG). I use OpenCV version 3.4.5 and Android Studio 3.3. The thing is that the `readNetFromTensorflow()` function's first argument is the `.pb` file (~17,4 MB) and the second is the `.pbtxt` (~284 KB).

Comment: hmm, it looks like the model is serialized in training mode (it should be in testing mode). There is a procedure called freezing which disabled all the training only nodes (there are in your graph).

Comment: That's interesting, because the `.pbtxt` is generated with this: `freeze_graph.freeze_graph('out/' + MODEL_NAME + '_graph.pbtxt', None, \
        False, 'out/' + MODEL_NAME + '.chkp', output_node_name, \
        "save/restore_all", "save/Const:0", \
        'out/frozen_' + MODEL_NAME + '.pb', True, "")`. So it should be frozen.

Comment: Is it possible to share mentioned `.pb` file?

Comment: Yes. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j4fw1rgnas2wnus/AACOwcQLsrVEC_pqXqOQ3EjZa?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Okay, I managed to solve my problem.** 
Firstly, I realized that the `.pb` and `.pbtxt` files are in the wrong directory and getting 2 `Failed to upload a file` information log. 
After putting the files into the right directory, I faced with problem: 
`error: (-215:Assertion failed) const_layers.insert(std::make_pair(name, li)).second in function 'void cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::{anonymous}::addConstNodes(opencv_tensorflow::GraphDef&, std::map<cv::String, int>&, std::set<cv::String>&)'` 
As [Dmitry Kurtaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6548453/dmitry-kurtaev) suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50643009/error-in-readnetfromtensorflow-in-c#comment88300243_50643009), I removed the `.pbtxt` from the `Dnn.readNetFromTensorflow`. After that I got error: 
`OpenCV(3.4.5) Error: Unspecified error (Can't create layer "flatten_1/Shape" of type "Shape") in cv::Ptr<cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::Layer> cv::dnn::experimental_dnn_34_v11::LayerData::getLayerInstance(), file /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp, line 513`

This led me to a link, which I found in [Dmitry Kurtaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6548453/dmitry-kurtaev)'s comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102280/opencv-cant-create-layer-flatten-1-shape-of-type-shape#comment95054047_54102280). After doing the suggested modifications (removing Const nodes, modifying and removing flatten nodes) on the `.pbtxt` file, finally I got no errors and got successfully running the neural net.

**Note:** Adding `K.backend.set_learning_phase(0)` before creating the model, also can be useful.